# How to convert a Swift object to a dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, service, alamofire

I'm relatively new to iOS programming. However, I would have assumed that Swift would have an automated way of converting objects to JSON and vice versa. That being said, I have found several libraries that can do this.

HOWEVER...

It seems that no matter how you post data to a web service (even using something like AlamoFire), the requests must be a dictionary. All these forums show examples of how easy it is to convert the returned JSON string to objects. True. But the request needs to be manually coded. That is, go through all of the object properties and map them as a dictionary.

So my question is this: Am I missing something? Have I got this all wrong and there's a super-easy way to either (a) send JSON (instead of a dictionary) in the REQUEST or (b) convert an object automatically to a dictionary?

Again, I see how easy it is to deal with a JSON response. I'm just looking for an automatic way to convert the request object I want to post to a web service into a format that a library like AlamoFire (or whatever) requires. With other languages this is fairly trivial, so I'm hoping there's an equally easy and automated way with Swift.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Swift currently does not support advanced reflection like Java or C# so the answer is: no, there is not an equally easy and automated way with pure Swift.

[Update] Swift 4 has meanwhile the `Codable` protocol which allows serializing to/from JSON and PLIST.

```
typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

Comment: indeed reflection is not as advanced as other languages but you still have some ways to achieve this, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971256/how-to-convert-a-swift-object-to-a-dictionary/32682463#32682463)

Comment: I wrote the answer in times of Swift 1.2.

Comment: just came here to make peace & to say that thx to Apple we can only agree now (in Swift 4) xoxo ;-)

Answer (score 50):

I must disagree with @Darko.

In **Swift 2**,

use **protocol oriented programming** and the simple reflection offered by **Mirror** class :

```
protocol JSONAble {}

extension JSONAble {
    func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        let otherSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in otherSelf.children {
            if let key = child.label {
                dict[key] = child.value
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

then you can use this protocol with your request class and produce the desired dictionary :

```
class JsonRequest : JSONAble {
    var param1 : String?
    // ...
}

let request = JsonRequest()
// set params of the request
let dict = request.toDict()
// use your dict
```

Comment: child.value is of type Any, you loose the type information. So, how to reflect a deep object tree with other objects, arrays, dictionaries, etc?

Comment: how is it undocumented ? see [Apple API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/s:VSs6Mirror5Child) please

Comment: Apple Swift Standard Library Reference: [`Mirror Structure Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) ... this is a release link instead of the previously commented "…/prerelease/ios/…" link.

Comment: The apple doc said: "Mirrors are used by playgrounds and the debugger." So can it be used in production code on App Store?

Comment: I found that this code also creates numerous memory leaks on the setting of the dictionary. Any ideas? I think this is related to it being created for the playground

Comment: It is important to note that mirrors are slow in terms of performance - see https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/

Comment: A little late I know, @Darko you can use an 'is' statement to check for the type of value. What I do is I mark my subclass objects as JSONAble also, and then check to see if the child value is that. If it is, I simply cast it to JSONAble and then recursively call .toDict() to get the nested JSON.

Answer (score 22):

My solution to this will be something like this:

```
extension Encodable {

    var dict : [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] else { return nil }
        return json
    }
}
```

and usage will be something like this:

```
movies.compactMap { $0.dict }
```

Answer (score 6):

Without using reflection, and works for nested objects (Swift 4):

```
protocol Serializable {
    var properties:Array<String> { get }
    func valueForKey(key: String) -> Any?
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
}

extension Serializable {
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any] {
        var dict:[String:Any] = [:]

        for prop in self.properties {
            if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? String {
                dict[prop] = val
            } else if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? Int {
                dict[prop] = val
            } else if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? Double {
                dict[prop] = val
            } else if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? Array<String> {
                dict[prop] = val
            } else if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? Serializable {
                dict[prop] = val.toDictionary()
            } else if let val = self.valueForKey(key: prop) as? Array<Serializable> {
                var arr = Array<[String:Any]>()

                for item in (val as Array<Serializable>) {
                    arr.append(item.toDictionary())
                }

                dict[prop] = arr
            }
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

Just implement properties and valueForKey for the custom objects you want to convert. For example:

```
class Question {
    let title:String
    let answer:Int

    init(title:String, answer:Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.answer = answer
    }
}
extension Question : Serializable {
    var properties: Array<String> {
        return ["title", "answer"]
    }

    func valueForKey(key: String) -> Any? {
        switch key {
        case "title":
            return title
        case "answer":
            return answer
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

You can add more value types in the toDictionary function if you need.

Comment: Isn't this answer going to be multiple times faster than using Mirror? Works for me

Comment: Except now you have to code everything twice? and adding a property means you have to update two places in code?

Answer (score 5):

The latest solution that I found after lots of digging throughout Stack Overflow is:

```
//This block of code used to convert object models to json string
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(requestData)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)

//This method is used to convert jsonstring to dictionary [String:Any]
func jsonToDictionary(from text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    let anyResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    return anyResult as? [String: Any]
}

//Use above method something like this
let params = jsonToDictionary(from: jsonString) ?? [String : Any]()
 
//Use params to pass in paramters
Alamofire.request(completeUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding:JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: myHeaders){
        
        response in

       //Do whatever you want with response of it.
        
    }
```

Note:

1. I combine this solution from multiple answers.
2. This solution i used with alamofire because alamofire only accept parameter at this format "[String:Any]".

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library. It has a "toJSON" method that converts your object to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

in short

```
let dict = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.map({ $0 }).reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.label] = $1.value }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example how to use Mirror with conversion to specific Dictionary type:

```swift
protocol DictionaryConvertible { }

extension DictionaryConvertible {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: CustomStringConvertible] {
        Dictionary(
            uniqueKeysWithValues: Mirror(reflecting: self).children
                .compactMap { child in
                    if let label = child.label,
                        let value = child.value as? CustomStringConvertible {
                        return (label, value)
                    } else {
                        return nil
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

model:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let number: String?
}
```

add this Extension :

```
extension Encodable {
    func asDictionary() throws -> [String: Any] {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
            throw NSError()
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

usage (magic):

```
try! userObj.asDictionary()
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.